# intent-filter url getting truncated after hashtag

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to filter all the URLs that came from a specific host and include a some data after a hashtag and an exclamation mark, so the pattern looks like "`http://myhost.com/bla/bla#!123456`", but the data after the hashtag isn't coming through the intent at all.

Here is the filter:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myhost.com" android:pathPattern=".*#!.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is the adb command i use to test this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://myhost.com/bla/bla#!123456"
```

but the output of this is:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://myhost.com/bla/bla }
```

and here it is already without the hashtag and the data after it.

And the last thing that is also strange is that if i change the pattern to be ".*" (to catch all the paths) after the intent starts the activity, the intent contains the full URL with the hashtag and the data after it.

Comment: try chage to `".#!*" `

Comment: it isn't working, the data after the exclamation mark is numerical not a bunch of exclamation marks

Comment: and this - `".*\\#!.*\\"` ?

Comment: no. still not working

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since i came across the same problem, I will post my findings here. I think the problem is that # is a reserved character: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html. The path part of the Uri gets truncated to "/bla/bla", that's why your pathPattern won't match. You need to set the pathPattern to "/bla/bla" and filter the data from the Uri string yourself from the Intent object with `intent.getData().toString().split("#")[1]` or something similar.